# The definition of a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

There are a whole bunch of equivalent definitions of a normal subgroup. Is it logically sound (with respect to the usual definitions) to include as a definition of normal, "$N$ is the kernel of some homomorphism $f$"?

Comment: Equivalent definitions usually require proof of equivalence.

Comment: This is precisely the first isomorphism theorem. If we define a normal subgroup $N$ to be a subgroup of $G$ such that $gNg^{-1}\in N$ for all $g\in G$ then the first isomorphism theorem states that every normal subgroup is the kernel of some homomorphism and the kernel of every homomorphism is a normal subgroup. Thus, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

It's logically sound.
Let $G$ be group, $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$.
$N$ is the kernel of the canonical homomorphism $G \rightarrow G/N$.
Conversely let $f\colon G \rightarrow G'$ be a group homomorphism.
$Ker(f)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: You write "_its_ normal subgroup" -- this would mean a group can only ever have one normal subgroup. If you don't mean it this way you could write something like "$N$ a normal subgroup of $G$".

Comment: @MattN. Thanks for the English grammar.